# Threejs camera lock to orientation of vehicle top down

Tags: three.js

Using Three.js, I have a camera that follows a car. I have orbit camera enabled but want the user to be able to switch to a top down view (already have that working). While in this top down view, however, I want the camera to always orient itself so the car is pointing North.

This is a similar effect to when using any maps app for directions, where it rotates the world to your perspective.

Basically I want to set the camera's "up" vector to point in the direction of my objects "forward" vector.

**Restriction:**

I don't think I can just attach my camera to the vehicle, as orbit controls then gets funky when rotating around.

**Example:**

Camera is centered on the target car.

[image]

As the car drives, it appears the world is rotating as the camera is locked to the car.

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? I can

Comment: I think you need update camera position and also rotations from model position/rotation. Right now I think you copying only position. Code sample should help. And i recomend using https://github.com/yomotsu/camera-controls/ if you have some camera animation. I using it lot of projects. There are lot of examples, maybe some example help you.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using `OrbitControls()` and is updating it every frame (in a `requestAnimationFrame()` function), your rotation will be locked.

A solution I can think of is adding a `THREE.Group()` and adding the camera to that group. Now, the group will have a separate transformations (PRS, XYZ) and is not locked with the orbit controls.

Add that group to the scene and lock its rotaion (or quaternion if preferred) to the cars rotation. If you didn't set the camera `lookAt()` function, you will be looking at the middle of the scene no matter what you assigned.

You can copy the cars rotation in two different methods. The first is to assign the `x, y, z` of the car's rotation to the group like this...

```js
cameraGroup.rotation.x = car.rotation.x;
cameraGroup.rotation.y = car.rotation.y;
cameraGroup.rotation.z = car.rotation.z;
```

This method best be used on case you would manually add the animation ease.

The second method is using the `copy()` function as shown below.

```js
cameraGroup.rotation.copy(car.rotation)
```

This method best be used in case you want to copy the quaternion and not the rotation. Moreover, you won't be able to add an animation ease!